# How to go backwards through the previous 12 months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a report that checks through the previous 12 months only. I have this code which is working:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
WHILE @date < GETDATE()
BEGIN
    --do marvelous things
    SET @date = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@date)
END
```

...however it brings the results back starting from June 2014 (as it is June 2015 today, obviously).

I would like the code to bring back results starting from June 2015 and then work backwards to June 2014, but am not sure how to do this...

Am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: To begin with, a **loop** is very often the wrong approach to do things in SQL. SQL is **set-oriented**, and you can do wonderful things with just one statement and without loops. So, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: order by COL_NAME desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE()
WHILE @date > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
BEGIN
    --do marvelous things
    SET @date = DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@date)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` clause in your query. Eg:

```
select * from your_table where date_col between @start_date and @end_date order by date_col desc;
```

`ASC` or `DESC` can be use to display your result in either ascending or descending order.

Since, you are looping your `SQL` query. Then,

Change

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

to

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = DATEADD(year,0,GETDATE()) // Current Year
```

And

```
SET @date = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@date)
```

to

```
 SET @date = DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@date)  // substracting one month after each iteration.
```